# Table's column value needed in file name in Spring Batch Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

In my project I am using Spring Batch to read data from database and generate files. I am using **JpaPagingItemReader** for reading data and **FlatFileItemWriter** for writing data. I have a requirement where I need one column value (same for all records) in generated file name. Can you please help me how to achieve this using Spring Batch.

Let me explain the requirement.

Suppose I need to read data from below table.

column1|column2|column3
abc1   |xyz    | pqr1
abc2   |xyz    | pqr2
abc3   |xyz    | pqr3

and I need column2 value in my file name. So filename should be spring_xyz_batch.txt.

I hope the requirement is clear to you.

***Note - I don't want to use any repository to get column value.***

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  Most of us here are happy to help you improve your craft, but are less happy acting as short-order unpaid programming staff. Show us your work so far as a [mcve], the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out. It may help to re-read [ask].

Comment: show more code. Or I can say that you can save that column value into a system property after you read it and then you can use that to make your file name.